# Lifting finite order automorphism of power series ring

Tags: power-series, p-adic-number-theory, automorphism-group

$\require{AMScd}$

Let $\mathcal{O}$ be an (finite) extension of the $p$-adic integers.. Denote by $R$ the power series ring $\mathcal{O} [[X_1, \dots, X_n]]$ and let $I$ be an ideal such that $R/I$ is integral and flat over $\mathcal{O}$.

Assume we have an $\mathcal{O}$-algebra automorphism $\varphi : R/I \to R/I$ of finite order $e$ with $e$ prime to $p$.

Can we always lift $\varphi$ to an automorphism $\phi : R \to R$ of finite ordrer $e$ (i.e. such that \begin{CD}
R @>\phi>> R\\
@VVV @VVV\\
R/I @>\varphi>> R/I
\end{CD} is commutative ?

Comment: How much do you know already about this problem? What’s the situation for the case $n=1$?

Comment: For starters I would like to see how to lift the Frobenius automorphism of $\Bbb{Z}_p(\zeta)$, with $\zeta$ a root of unity of order $p^f-1$ to, an automorphism of order $f$ of $\Bbb{Z}_p[[X]]$.

Comment: Thanks for the illuminating comment, @JyrkiLahtonen.